how do I reenable folding arrows in the ruler
I use vscode.
Foldable code blocks used to have fold/unfold arrows in the ruler, now however, we have the sticky scroll.
Is there a way to re-enable the fold arrows in the ruler?

Is your Editor: Show Folding Controls set to always or mouseover and not never?  And by ruler do you mean the gutter area on the left just ti the right of the line numbers?

Hey Mark
Editor: Show Folding Controls is set to always.
I found the appropriate settings and will answer myself.

I found the appropriate setting, Editor: Folding check box.
I also found the appropriate setting to turn off the automatic top fold, Editor › Sticky Scroll: Enabled checkbox.
